# How to get WebRTC logs on Safari Browser

Tags: ios, safari, webkit, webrtc, mobile-safari

I have been trying to get the webrtc logs for my web application running over safari browser, similar to what we get in firefox by going to the page `about:webrtc` and on chrome by using `chrome://webrtc-internals`.

Alternatively, Is there any js API for webrtc to get the logs on the console itself, similar to what we use in Native Android and iOS applications using the RTCLogger.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have the same question. We can see log of Android and iOS, but cannot in web.

Comment: looking for the same logs, let us know I you find out something

Comment: Aagman please check my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Safari `Version 15.4 (17613.1.17.1.13)`, useful information can be retrieved this way:

- In `Preferences...` -> `Advanced`, ensure `Show Develop menu in menu bar` is enabled.
- In the Develop menu Settings, select the `Console` tab, then ensure `WebRTC Logging` is not `Off` (and so choose either `Basic` or `Verbose`).

At that point the Console will show WebRTC events and data structures.

e.g.:

[image]

Comment: In Safari 16.4, there is no `Console` tab under `Develop`, and no settings overall under the `Develop` menu either.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

If you open the Safari and also open [the console application](https://support.apple.com/guide/console/welcome/mac), you can filter WebRTC logs with these filters:

- category:WebRTC
- process:safari (optional)

just copy-paste them one by one to the search bar in the console application. Actually, the second one is optional (process:safari).

I'm not sure about the others but at least you can see:

- SDP offers and answers
- ICE candidates
- WebRTC statistics
- incoming and outgoing video frame counters

#### Fun Fact

Based on [the official documentation of WebRTC](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/logging/) you can't see logs on Safari :)

## Useful Infos

- Do you know there is a WebRTC menu in the Safari. Check the **Develop > WebRTC** sub-menu
- Check the [*Safari Technology Preview*](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) app for more options and flags
- If you’re not logged in as an administrator, you need to enter an administrator name and password to search for and view log messages.

Comment: Is there some other Safari option that needs to be enabled in order for these to work? Following instructions, I'm not seeing any WebRTC logs (ex ICE candidates, etc).

Answer (score 1):

First, enable `Safari > Settings > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar` as bellow:

[image]

Then, click `Safari > Develop > Show JavaScript Console` as bellow:

[image]

Next, click the `Setting` icon, select the `Console` tab, set the `WebRTC Logging` to `Basic`, as bellow:

[image]

Back to the `JavaScript Console`, there are WebRTC logs, as bellow:

[image]

Test on Safari 16.6