# How to see the amount of data transfer during pixel streaming in chrome devtool?

Tags: debugging, networking, google-chrome-devtools, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to see how much will be transfered during a pixel streaming session on the browser. Take a look at this demo for example, after the page is loaded, I see no more request/response or data transfer when I interact with the scene.
https://share.arcware.cloud/b84bd175-ad07-4896-9a67-2282eb088564

What I'm understanding is that Pixel Streaming is something like a socket connection, where every interaction of the user is sent to the server, the server modifies the scene based on that interaction and sends back the result? Is my understanding correct? If it is there should be constant data transfer between the browser and the pixel streaming server, but why do I see nothing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixel Streaming utilises WebRTC. The WebSocket connection is used to facilitate the WebRTC connection, in a process known as [Signalling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling).

In this instance, WebRTC is being used to share the video & audio from the streamer server (in this case, the Unreal Engine). The user inputs (e.g. mouse clicks) are being sent from the user to the streamer over a WebRTC data channel.

To see the data transfer, you need to use the specific WebRTC tools in the browser. To access this, use the below URLs depending on which browser you use:

- Chrome - chrome://webrtc-internals
- Edge - edge://webrtc-internals
- Firefox - about:webrtc
- Safari - no URL, but [possible in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036996/how-to-get-webrtc-logs-on-safari-browser)

Using these tools, you will be able to see bitrate, FPS, bytes sent/received, and more information relating to the connection.